# CompilerThread state on tomcat 6

Tags: java, multithreading

Runnig a thread dump for a tomcat process I just notice the follow:

```
"CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x02b57400 nid=0xe0c waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
```

My understood is that the CompilerThread(anynumber) are run by JVM for compiling bytecode into native code, but I would like a confirmation on this.
But my main concern is about the thread saying to be in 'waiting on condition' but later declared in RUNNABLE state. 
What am I misunderstanding ? And finally what's the meaning of [0x00000000] ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

So a field by field breakdown :

1. `"CompilerThread0"` - Tomcat has the compiler thread for compiling JSPs.  JSPs get compiled into a java class the first time they're accessed.
2. `daemon` - it's a daemon thread so as not to keep your app alive when you choose to exit
3. `prio=10` - highest priority so that JSP compilation takes precedence over other requests.
4. `nid=0xe0c` - don't actually know. ;)
5. `waiting on condition [0x0000000]` - the thread is currently blocking waiting for someone to signal it to wake up and do something.  as with nid, I'm not actually sure of what the [0x000000] refers to.  I suspect that it would hold the address of an object monitor if that's what we were waiting on.
6. `java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE` - a thread waiting on a condition is still seen to be as RUNNABLE

One thing that looks confusing it first is that the thread is RUNNABLE even though it's waiting.  This is counterintuitive, but it has to do with the fact that the JVM differentiates between a condition and an object monitor (e.g. the mechanism used for wait/notify).

Hope that helps!

Comment: well it is really counter intuitive, because some other thread are marked as 'waiting on condition' and in a state of WAITING(sleeping). The nid is the OS native process id